# Set a focus state to a field+angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, focus

I have a focus related problem. what i need is to set a focus state over a field in the onInit function of the component, the first field. but i can´t aim the field properly.

i have tried

```
export class EgrCrearRecetaComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('paciente') ePaciente; 
  ...
 }
```

and in the onInit function

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.buildForm();
   // try to set
   this.ePaciente.nativeElement.focus();
   ...
  }
```

this is what i forgot to tell, i'm using reactive forms, so i can`t use #paciente, i'm using

```
<input type="text" pInputText formControlName="paciente" class="form-control" placeholder="Dni Paciente">
```

thsi is the formbuilder structure in the component:

```
buildForm(): void {
this.recetaform = this.fb.group({
  paciente: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(7), <any>Validators.maxLength(9)]],
  femision: [this.fechaHoy(), [<any>Validators.required]],
  servicio: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  idServicio: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  turno: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  prestador: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  idPrestador: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  diagnostico: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  idDiagnostico: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  productofgn: this.fb.group({
    cb: [''],
    producto: [''],
    lote: [''],
    cant: [''],
    dias: [''],
  })
});
```

}

Sorry friends. I get the same error over and over.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Move it to AfterViewChecked()

```
...
import { AfterViewChecked} from '@angular/core';
..

export class EgrCrearRecetaComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
....
toFocus=true;
ngAfterViewChecked() {
   if (this.toFocus) {
       this. ePaciente.nativeElement.focus();
   }
   this.toFocus = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Focus your field after view has been initialized:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    // Work around for "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" 
    setTimeout(()=> { this.ePaciente.nativeElement.focus() }, 10);
}
```

Here is a working [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1eDTqpfYbGxaO3WbI6d2?p=preview)

Comment: it works  but in the console i got: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined for this field. many times!!!

Comment: how are you defining `ePaciente`? can you update the code in the plunker link I provided ? I dont get any errors

Answer (score 0):

You should use another component life cycle hook - `ngAfterViewInit` as it is fired as soon as its view and its children views are initialized. 
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Also inside that hook callback use setTimeout to be sure that the first change detection had chance to run and elements are rendered (so as focusable input). You don't have to specify the delay parameter as you only want to wait for the next tick.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ePaciente.nativeElement.focus();
    });
}
```